# Pygame. How to make a rect change direction on collision (boundary check)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Part of an assignment I'm working on is making a ball bounce around the screen, I can make it move, but my boundary test doesn't seem to be working: the ball simply moves in direction instead of changing direction. So to clarify, what I want to ball to do is change direction as it hits the screen edge.

```
import sys
import pygame

SCREEN_SIZE = 750, 550
BALL_DIAMETER = 16
BALL_RADIUS = BALL_DIAMETER // 2
MAX_BALL_X = SCREEN_SIZE[0] - BALL_DIAMETER
MAX_BALL_Y = SCREEN_SIZE[1] - BALL_DIAMETER
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

LEFT = 11
RIGHT = 12
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 20)

pygame.display.set_caption("Breakout")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' '''
        self.ball = pygame.Rect(300, 730 -
                                BALL_DIAMETER,
                                BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER)

    # Draw ball
    def draw_ball(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,
                           WHITE, (self.ball.left
                           + BALL_RADIUS, self.ball.top +
                           BALL_RADIUS), BALL_RADIUS)

    # Updates the coordinates by adding the speed components
    def move_ball(self, x, y):
        self.xspeed = x
        self.yspeed = y
        self.ball = self.ball.move(self.xspeed, self.yspeed)


        # bounds check
        if self.ball.left <= 0:
            self.ball.left = 0
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        elif self.ball.left >= MAX_BALL_X:
            self.ball.left = MAX_BALL_X
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        if self.ball.top < 0:
            self.ball.top = 0
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed
        elif self.ball.top >= MAX_BALL_Y:
            self.ball.top = MAX_BALL_Y
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed

# shows a message on screen, for testing purposes
class Text:
    def show_message(self, message):
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 20)
        font = self.font.render(message,False, WHITE)
        screen.blit(font, (200, 400))


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' '''
    def run(self):
        b = Ball()
        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            # fps lock, screen fill and method call for input
            clock.tick(60)
            screen.fill(BLACK)
            b.draw_ball()
            b.move_ball(5, -5)

            # used to keep track of various elements
            # Text().show_message("P: " + str(p))

            pygame.display.flip()

# Creates instance of the game class, and runs it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only call to `move_ball` uses a constant vector.
Since you never change the call parameters, the ball moves only that way.

```
b.move_ball(5, -5)
```

Yes, you change the vector components within `move_ball` when you hit a wall.  However, on the next call, you change them back to the original values and move the ball in the original direction.

You have to initialize the vector *outside* `move_ball`, and then let the routine access the existing vector when it's called.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I added two global variables "x" and "y" and initialized self.xspeed and self.yspeed by using those two variables. This solved my problem.